# How do I produce xHE-AAC Audio files under Ubuntu?

Tags: codecs, aac, m4a

Under Ubuntu I can easily produce AAC files: AAC-LC, HE-AAC and even HE-AACv2. But how do I produce the *newest* form of AAC: xHE-AAC which promises to give a consistent performance at low data rates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many years no Open Source xHE-AAC encoder existed for Linux but that has all changed in early 2020 with the initial release of Christian R. Helmrich's `exhale`. This builds easily under Ubuntu, I have tested under 22.04 where only a few steps are required to build the very latest version:

**Building exhale...**

Use the following steps in sequence, copying each command and pasting into a Terminal window (*Note: If you have a 32bit installation you will need: `BUILD32=1`*) :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/exhale_build && cd $HOME/Desktop/exhale_build
wget https://gitlab.com/ecodis/exhale/-/archive/v1.2.0/exhale-v1.2.0.tar.gz
tar xvf exhale-v1.2.0.tar.gz && cd exhale-v1.2.0
make BUILD32=0 release
sudo cp -v bin/exhale /usr/local/bin
```

And this has successfully installed our xHE-AAC encoder; test your installation as follows:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ exhale | head -n 6

  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 | exhale - ecodis extended high-efficiency and low-complexity encoder |
 |                                                                     |
 | version 1.2.0 (x64, built on Jan 19 2023) - written by C.R.Helmrich |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
andrew@corinth:~$
```

And now for a few usage tips:

**Using exhale...**

To test `exhale` I would strongly advise the use of a 'standard' wav file; this can be downloaded and extracted as follows:

```
cd $HOME/Desktop
wget http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/A-codecs/lossless/luckynight.wav.bz2
bunzip2 -v luckynight.wav.bz2
```

And now this files can easily be encoded to xHE-AAC using a selected preset bit-rate mode from 1 - 10 with 1 being about 64kbit/s and 10 being about 192kbit/s. The following encodes to about 96kbit/s:

```
exhale 3 luckynight.wav luckynight_USAC.m4a
```

Congratulations, you have produced an xHE-AAC file under Ubuntu!

**Notes...**

- [exhale Wiki :: Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://gitlab.com/ecodis/exhale/-/wikis/faq): Some useful questions and answers in particular a table showing the relationship between bit-rate mode and resulting kbit/s.
- [Topic: exhale - Open Source xHE-AAC encoder](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=118888.0): The Hydrogen Audio home for `exhale`. Importantly the developer posts here and is available for feedback.
- [FFmpeg Ticket: Support USAC / xHE-AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8411): The crucial ticket to get a decoder available in avcodec and thence in MPlayer, mpv, vlc etc.
- **Use with abcde?**: I created a patch a while back that enables USAC / xHE-AAC output from abcde. You will need the git abcde and [this patch...](https://www.andrews-corner.org/downloads/abcde_USAC.diff.gz)
- **What about playback??**: Best playback for Linux users at the moment is to use Wine and the latest release of Foobar 2000. You will *also* need to install version 1.7 or later of the fdk-aac packet decoder found [here...](https://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_pd_aac)